# Yii infinite scroll with noconflict

Tags: jquery, yii

I have implemented Yii infinite scrolling using Yii framework. It is working fine without Jquery. If I add the Jquery infinite scrolling is not working. If I remove the Jquery menu toggle functions are not working. I am using menu function is Bootstrap collapse. I had been added the no conflict() function. It was not working. i added my codes for your reference. please suggest me suitable answer

```
<?php $this->widget('ext.yiinfinite-scroll.YiinfiniteScroller', array(
'contentSelector' => '#posts',
'itemSelector' => 'div.post',
'loadingText' => 'Loading...',
'donetext' => 'There is no more posts... my only friend, the end',
'pages' => $pages,
```

)); ?>

Answer (score 1):

Use jquery conflict  like this

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

and replace your menu toggle jquery with `$j`

Comment: how can i use $j variable in my toggle code.. i shows below code. suggest me how to call that variable